# Proof of a function that is Riemann Integrable using its definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given the function : $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ if $x$ is not $0$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x = 0$

Prove that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ by the definition of Riemann Integrable. So How do I show that the lower sum equal to the upper sum of this function?

Comment: Since I don't want to check what $L$ is used to mean there, I don't know what to explain in the approach either.

Comment: I would suggest you write the definition, since nobody wants to look it up in 500+ pages book. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial how to write math on this page.

Comment: You most have been given more information. The value of the integral is not trivial (Wolfram gives about 0.504), so I don't see how you can use this definition for your proof.

Comment: Okay what if I can use the upper sum and the lower sum to show that this is Riemann integrable?

Comment: @Tsharkie A possible approach. (P.S. use "\sin" in math mode, instead of "sin")

Answer (score 1):

First consider any partition $\mathcal{P}$, and take the first left interval of $\mathcal{P}$, namely $P_1=[0,a_1]$. Since $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, the corresponding summand to the lewer and upper Riemann sum of $P_1$ is $-a_1$ or $a_1$ respectively. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a_1,1]$ (so Riemann integrable in $[a_1,1]$), considering all partitions you have the difference between the lower and the upper Riemann integrals $$\overline{\int\limits_{0}^1} f(x)dx - \underline{\int\limits_{0}^1} f(x)dx\leq 2a_1.$$ Taking more refined partitions you have $a_1\to 0$. I hope you got the main idea.

Comment: okay you only show the Upper sum and the lower sum of P1, what about P2?

Comment: @Tsharkie There the problem is standard: uniform continuity (which you have for continuous functions on compact sets) tells you how fine to make the partition for a given closeness of upper/lower sum.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? @Ian

Comment: @Tsharkie Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Take $a_1<\varepsilon/4$ so $2a_1<\varepsilon/2$. On $[a_1,1]$, the Heine-Cantor theorem tells you that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Setting $\varepsilon'=\varepsilon/2$ in the definition of uniform continuity, obtain an appropriate $\delta$ that doesn't depend on $x$. Then partition $[a_1,1]$ into subintervals of length $\delta$. This will make the difference between the upper and lower sum at most $\varepsilon'(1-a_1)<\varepsilon/2$. Adding up the two pieces gives something less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Is it possible to show that the upper integral equals to the lower integral in every partition in [0,1] ??

Comment: @Tsharkie Technically yes, but I would say that the approach of actually bringing the upper and lower *integrals* into the problem is usually more cumbersome than working with partitions.